# Changing number of data-based size intervals in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am a beginner using the QGIS program.

Is there any way to change the number of symbol sizes produced in the size assistant? (in the image it produced 7 but I would rather have 4. 0-8, 8-16, 16-24, 24-32).

I know that this can be done in a graduated symbology type but my layers are already in a categorized type based on another property.

[image]